# C#: LINQ: If Null assign default value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string[] fields as {prop1 = val1, prop2 = val2, amount = 30.00}. And I try to get the value of amount as follows:

```
TransactionAmount = fields?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower().Contains("amount"))?.Split('=')[1].ToString();
```

How do I assign a default value if amount(not fields)is null?

```
TransactionAmount = fields?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower().Contains("amount"))?.Split('=')[1].ToString() : "0.00"; //this is not working
```

Thank you

Comment: Overuse of `?.`. Consider how the problem can be expressed without such. While this might seem like a 'pointless exercise', it really does lead to a [readable] solution.

Comment: Does it necessarily need to be a one-liner? It would be easier to write it and easier to read it if you just split it into two lines: get single or default + return the value or null if not found.

Comment: My string[] fields has a lot of elements, so I was trying to find a simpler solution to the issue. I could try wrapping it in !string.IsNullOrEmpty(linq query) ? (linq query) : "0.00". I was looking for a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the null-coalescing operator. (or the ?? operator)

The two below are the same:

```
return A ?? B;//Using the null-coalescing operator.

if (A == null) return B;//Using if-else.
else return A;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Check whether the array is null:

```
//Is Fields null? if not, use fields, otherwise, use the
//new string array with the "DEFAULT_VALUE".
(fields ?? new string[] { "DEFAULT_VALUE" }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower().Contains("amount")).Split('=')[1];
```

And check whether FirstOrDefault returned null:

```
(fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower().Contains("amount")) ?? "DEFAULT_VALUE").Split('=')[1];
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry my bad. I changed it.

Comment: @Tommy, you had it right the first time. My question had a bug, I edited my question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper I changed my answer to include both.